# Access controls inside listview DataTemplete

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want To access named controls inside listview datatemplet i followed this: [How to Access a Named Control Inside a XAML DataTemplate (using CSharp](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-access-named-control)

```
itemlistview.ItemsSource=new List<MyObject>();    
foreach (var item in itemListView.Items)
                {
                    var _Container = itemListView.ItemContainerGenerator
                        .ContainerFromItem(item);
                    var _Children = AllChildren(_Container);

                    var _FirstName = _Children.OfType<StackPanel>()
                        .First(x => x.Name.Equals("subjectListItem"));

                    _FirstName.Visibility =
                        Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
```

But the problem in `var item in itemListView.Items` it retruns the MyObject which i passed to listview ItemsSource Not the controles inside the datatemplete.
So How can I return The Controls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(object)` should return an instance of `ListViewItem` that contains the data of the `item`.

But, this practice is discourage in WPF/WinRT frameworks. The "right" way is to control the data and have the UI react to it.

Something like:

```
// in code
var list = new List<MyObject>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.IsSomethingVisible = false;
}
itemlistview.ItemsSource = list;

<!--in XAML-->
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsSomethingVisible,
                   Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}".../>

<!--The converter is defined in resources of some higher level-->
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```